# Arrangement of people in 2 taxis.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways in which 6 people can be seated in 2 taxis of 4 seats each if internal arrangement matters.

---

My answer is $\frac{6!6!}{4!2!}$

But the answer key says different. Please help

Comment: What does the answer key say?

Comment: @GuachoPerez  aniket is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So taking into consideration that internal seating arrangement matters, in plain and simple language, I can say that there are $4 \times 2 = 8$ different seats and I have to place and arrange $6$ people in them.

The no. of ways to do so is given by $^8P_6=\frac{8!}{(8-6)!}=\frac{8!}{2!}$

Comment: Hmm u r right. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: he's in mathematics department.

Comment: Actually I am in the physics department. Maybe I have met him once. :-)

Comment: I'm not able to chat there. R u good at integration?

Comment: Tell me what problem you have got.